# Construction of the real numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In my textbook a construction of the real numbers is given as follows:

> Define the set $D$ as the Cartesian product of $\mathbb{Z}$ and the set of sequences of the digits $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. In otherwords, an element of $\mathbb{R}$ consists of an integer $a_0$ and a sequence of digits $(a_n)^\infty _{n = 1}$.
>
> $$a = a_0.a_1a_2a_3...$$

I'm a little confused how this works exactly. If we take an arbitrary ordered pair from the set, we would have $(a,b)$. Here, $a$ is from the integers and $b$ is from the sequence $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. I'm not seeing how we obtain the reals from this definition. Could someone explain what this definition is trying to say?

Comment: Set of *sequences*. For example, $1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, ...$ would be such a sequence; when paired with an integer $3$ it would give you $\pi$. This definition has a problem with $0.999...$ and $1.000...$ being formally different elements.

Comment: Well, any real number can be written as a decimal.  $\pi= 3.141592653589\cdots$ for example so your pair is $(3,\{1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,\cdots\}$.  I don't know how they plan to handle $1=.9999\cdots$.

Comment: Ah right, I see the distinction now @Abstraction. Thanks for that clarification.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what element of $D$ corresponds to the real number $-1/3$?

Comment: I guess $(-1, \{3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, ...\})$ would @BarryCipra

Comment: @Philip, are you sure it's not $(-1,\{6,6,6,6,6,6,\ldots\})$?

Comment: Yes? I'm not sure what you're saying, sorry!

Comment: @Philip, I'm just getting at a slight disconnect between the way real numbers are normally written as decimals and the way the set $D$ is defined.  For non-negative reals, there's no problem; for example, $\pi=3.14159\ldots=3+{1\over10}+{4\over100}+{1\over1000}+\cdots$.  But $-\pi=-3.14159\not=-3+{1\over10}+{4\over100}+{1\over1000}+\cdots$.

Comment: @BarryCipra $x=\text{sgn}(x) (\left\lfloor|x|\right\rfloor+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_i 10^{-i})$

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak Bad idea: $-0.8 = (-1)(0+8*10^{-1})$, but you can't represent it with $(0, (8, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...))$ or it will be indistinguishable from $+0.8$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Another try: $x(a, \{a_{i}\})=\begin{cases}\text{sgn}(a)(|a|+\sum a_i 10^{-i}),&\text{for } a\neq 0 \\2(\sum a_i 10^{-i})-1,& \text{for } a=0\end{cases}$